# Speeding Up -[setImage:] With UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am currently working on an application that incorporates image downloading and displaying around 20 images inside of a scroll view.  The downloading works great, and so does the conversion from NSData to UIImage.  However, I am experiencing a 1 second lag spike if multiple downloads finish at the same time, and therefore if multiple image properties of UIImageView are set within close proximity.  How can I reduce this lag?

Here is my code called when the download completes.  This could be called 20 times or so within a 1 second interval.

```
// _imageDataQueue is a dispatch_queue created in the init method
dispatch_async(_imageDataQueue, ^{

    // data is an NSData object set when the download completes
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (image) {

            // this is stripped down, but it is just some simple logic
            // and eventually the image is set
            [theImageView setImage:image];

        } else {

            // called if there is no image and theImageView's image is set
            // to a cached image
            [theImageView setImage:someCachedUIImage];

        }

    });

});
```

Perhaps I could queue the setImage calls?  What would the best way to fix this?

Comment: r u using tableview to display images ?

Comment: Negative.  I am using a UIScrollView, as some logic is added since the images are of different sizes.

Comment: Maybe a dispatch_sync call would slow things down a bit (or a serial queue instead of a concurrent one...), but it would prevent UI lag, which is the thing the user will notice.